# Tracking Touches in an Android application

Tags: java, android

I know this is probably pretty basic but I'm having a hard time finding an answer online about this.  I am making an android app and want to track where the user touched with a dot and display this dot throughout their use of the app.  So eventually there will be a bunch of dots around the screen.  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html

You should do a google search before asking stuff like this.

After you make an `OnTouchListener`, call on whatever view you want, `View.setOnTouchListener()` and as a parameter put the `OnTouchListener` you made.

As you make the OnTouchListener, you'll have to override a method called `onTouch(MotionEvent event);` and you can work with the parameter `event` to get its X and Y values. Afterwords, you could use those X and Y to draw those dots in the `onDraw()` method you are going to override.